# fill tree view node using dataset c#

Tags: c#

friends
i have this code to fill Parent Node and Child node from 2 Table

First Parent Table Is Category

Child Table is Expensive

Water_Category       (parent node)==table Category

```
water month 1     (child node) == table Expensive

water for month 2
```

Gas Gategory

```
gas for month 1
gas for mont2
```

what is my problem:
my problem this code fill tree view with parent node only from table Category 
and not fill child node from table Expensive

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.dPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=azouz(2016)");
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Category", cn);
OleDbDataAdapter daSub = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Expensive", cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Category");
daSub.Fill(ds, "Expensive");
ds.Relations.Add("Cat_Expensive", ds.Tables["Category"].Columns["Catid"], ds.Tables["Expensive"].Columns["Catid"]);

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Category"].Rows)
{
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["Category"].ToString());

    foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Expensive"))
    {
        tn.Nodes.Add(drChild["ExpensiveName"].ToString());
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a not creating a new tree node for "Expensive".

You create another treenode in second foreach for the child iterating, and add the child node to parent node "tn"

Something like  below (Based on your code, untested).

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Category"].Rows)
{
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["Category"].ToString());

    foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Expensive"))
    {
        //Create a child tree node here
        TreeNode tnChild = new TreeNode(drChild["Expensive"].ToString());
        tn.Nodes.Add(tnChild );

    }

}
```

A very old but conceptually very simple example :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287575(v=vs.71).aspx